# What do you call the land area around a pond?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

Usually "shore" and "beach" are used when talking about a large body of water. But what if we talk about a pond? Is the area around it still called a beach/shore?

Comment: I wouldn't use those words. I'd talk about the _edge_ of the pond, but I have no particular word for the land around it.

Comment: @ColinFine the wikipedia article on ponds uses the word "shore".

Comment: Note that the area around a pond has no typical structure -- may be flat, may be sloped, may be marshy, may be dry, etc.  So, aside from very generic terms such as "shore", terms specific to the individual conditions are apt to be used.

Comment: It would take some research but I suggest that both 'beach' and 'shore' incorporate the idea of waves. Both beaches and shores are not mere lines in the ground but are areas within which tide and wave motion occur. So whether an inland lake or a sea lake or a fjord, all having waves, 'beach' or 'shore' is appropriate. But ponds have ripples, not waves.

Comment: The context, that is the geomorphological situation, can vary. If the pond water borders directly onto vegetation with no exposed soil and the land rises slowly, there is no bank, shore, beach or  anything. I'd call that prosaically the edge of the pond.

Comment: I would think that "beach" implies an area of bare sand or rock at the edge of a body of water, regardless of its size.  Generally more common on larger bodies of water since a deep tide is what clears the shore of mud and vegetation, but there are definitely beaches on smaller lakes as well.

Comment: If I was coming to mow the lawn I would have to ask if the ***surround*** was landscaped or hardscaped, so I knew if I needed to bring a small push mower as well.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

***Bank***

> The land alongside or sloping down to a river or lake.

-[Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bank)

From [*Farming Fresh Water Prawns: A Manual...*](https://books.google.it/books?id=eXRbywIp5pQC&pg=PA88&dq=%22embankments%22+%22pond+bank%22,+%22of+the+ponds%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiH5aOP6PHfAhW_IbkGHT3wCroQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22embankments%22%20%22pond%20bank%22%2C%20%22of%20the%20ponds%22&f=false)

The *banks* of the pond (sometimes referred to as *embankments or bunds*)...

> [image: excerpt form cited book]

Also:

> In geography, the word bank generally refers to the land alongside a body of water. Different structures are referred to as banks in different fields of geography...The ***shoreline of ponds***, swamps, estuaries, reservoirs, or lakes are also of interest in limnology and are sometimes referred to as banks.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_(geography))

Comment: But not all ponds are surrounded by embankments.

Comment: @HotLicks That's true....but logically speaking the edge of the pond _has_ to be higher than the pond surface to hold the water in: otherwise it would be a marsh or swamp. Anyway, where I grew up, most ponds were man-made to provide water for cattle, and were _always_ banked.

Comment: There are parts of the country where many cow ponds are simply holes scooped in the soil of a pasture.  Especially after the cows get in with their hooves it's hard to say where the pond ends and the "bank" begins.

Comment: @HotLicks Know what you mean...usually a morass of churned mud. Good place to lose your boots.

Comment: @HotLicks - Ah, but all ponds have a *surround*.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are talking about a pond which is a natural part of the landscape - not an artificial pond e.g. garden pond.

In Britain I would think the most likely used name for the land area adjacent to such a natural pond to be ***the bank*** - the same as a *river bank*.

I'm very familiar with the Norfolk Broads. They are artificial lakes, which were created from peat-diggings in the medieval period, (admittedly a bit larger than anything which in Britain might be called *a pond*).  Connected by a network of rivers, they are today an important holiday area for boating, sailing, wildlife study etc.

I would refer to the edge of one of the "broads" as ***the bank*** - though the banks are substantially inaccessible due to reed growth. However where the reeds are cleared, mooring staithes have been created. People talk about mooring their boat at the river bank.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get technical, the land area around the pond is the **littoral** (noun) or the **littoral** (adjective) **zone**.

Whereas dictionaries define **littoral** in terms of a lake or sea:

([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/littoral)):

> adjective
>   1. of or relating to the shore of a sea, lake, or ocean
>   2. biology
>   inhabiting the shore of a sea or lake or the shallow waters near the shore
>   *littoral fauna*
>
> noun
>   3. a coastal or shore region

([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/littoral)):

> littoral adjective (Entry 1 of 2)
>   : of, relating to, or situated or growing on or near a shore especially of the sea
>   // *littoral* waters
>
> littoral noun (Entry 2 of 2)
>   : a coastal region
>   *especially* : the shore zone between high tide and low tide points

However, the usage of **littoral** in referring to ponds seems to be standard in the pond and bio-aquatic fields.  (**emphasis** mine in examples below)

From the [University of California Museum of Paleontology](http://www.ucmp.berkeley.edu/exhibits/biomes/freshwater.php):

> The topmost zone near the shore of a lake or pond is the ***littoral zone***. This zone is the warmest since it is shallow and can absorb more of the Sun's heat. It sustains a fairly diverse community, which can include several species of algae (like diatoms), rooted and floating aquatic plants, grazing snails, clams, insects, crustaceans, fishes, and amphibians. In the case of the insects, such as dragonflies and midges, only the egg and larvae stages are found in this zone. The vegetation and animals living in the littoral zone are food for other creatures such as turtles, snakes, and ducks.

From [ponds.org](http://www.ponds.org/littoralzones.html):

> **Littoral zones** are areas that are created on the edge of ponds that are to serve as a growth area for aquatic plants.

From [Kasco Marine](https://kascomarine.com/pond-lake-zone-identification/), a manufacturer of fountains, aerators, and other pond accessories:

> The **Littoral Zone** is the shore area of the lake or pond. The littoral zone consists of the area from the dry land sloping to the open water and can be very narrow or very wide. Typically oligotrophic or young ponds have narrow littoral zones due to their steep sides and eutrophic or old ponds have wide littoral zones due to their gently sloping shoreline and sides. The littoral zone is shallow and gets a lot of nutrients from runoff and non-point source pollution. Therefore, it typically has an abundance of aquatic plant and algae growth. Some other common inhabitants of the littoral zone are cattails, reeds, crawfish, snails, insects, zooplankton, and small fish.

Answer (score 1):

I live adjacent to a pond in New England (specifically, Spy Pond in Arlington, MA). People around here commonly call the area around it the *shore*, and the border of the water specifically as the *shoreline*.

For instance, this article on a town-related website:

> [Public input sought for Spy Pond shore protection](https://www.yourarlington.com/arlington-archives/town-school/environment/13862-edge-112717.html)
>
> The Arlington Conservation Commission and its partners wish to mitigate erosion and preserve the public shoreline to improve the ecological structure and function of Spy Pond.

Answer (score 0):

In English, if I were in a pond and want to get out of the pond, then I may say:

> After swimming, I will get on [dry] land.

I put "dry" in brackets, because that is optional.

It is possible to use "shoreline" or "shore" to describe the edge of a pond.

Sometimes, "beach" would be used to describe a small reservoir's land boundary or an ocean's land boundary.